# Entity Framework Connection String does not work in Windows App

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Am having a little problem connecting to a database at a clients using EF.

I can connect using a connection string...

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = null;

string connection = "Data Source=SERVER; Initial Catalog=DATABASE; User ID=USER; Password=PASSWORD; Persist Security Info=True; Pooling=False;"

 thisConnection = new SqlConnection(string.Format(connection));
 thisConnection.Open();
```

However, when I use EF and update my app.config to connection string below, I cannot connect...Any hints?

```
<add name="dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
     data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DATABASE;ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;multipleactiveresultsets=True; Persist Security Info=True; Pooling=False;
     App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The error = 'The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString'

Answer (score 1):

In EF, the user name key should be `User ID` (not `ID`)

So

```
<add name="dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
     data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DATABASE;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;multipleactiveresultsets=True; Persist Security Info=True; Pooling=False;
     App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: uhmmm...this may be a stupid question but how do I mark as answer?

Comment: There's a little check-mark icon below the Vote-Up/Vote-Down icons on the left of the answer.  I'm glad it helped!  Thanks